# What would be the best way to make a vampire story with a bit of romance without it being crappy?

Tags: fiction, plot

So I'm trying to write a story about a vampire couple who are on a quest, to become human again, it is set in a medieval style era.

It is somewhat of a romance but I don't want it to be too cliche or crappy.

Please, it would mean a lot to get some feedback from the story writing community!

Comment: this is too vague and if you're worried about it being stolen, really shouldn't be posting on the internet.

Comment: I changed it so it isnt very vague. But about the internet part, i should've gone with my gut in the first place and explained the story abit more...

Comment: If it has vampires, it’s 4/5 the way to being cliched and crappy. This is the reality of trends.

Comment: Maybe try [this](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/World_of_Darkness).

Comment: Hi @DerpymanMT! Welcome to Writing.SE! If you have time, you might want to take a look at the [tour] and [help] pages. You should have an explanation regarding why you've got so many downvotes, and why the question will likely get closed. As a Q&A community, we look for questions that can plausibly have one answer - that is questions that are not too broad (but not too specific either - questions that can help other people, not just you). Another thing we do not do is help you come up with an idea of what to write. It's your story after all.

Comment: Oh... Yeah now i read it... I will delete the question now, Edit never mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer, I must admit to the world: ***I am a carnivore.***
That's right, people! I eat meat. Bacon, beef, pork, chicken, turkey -- I shamelessly and without guilt consume them all, and ***enjoy it.***

I am not the only one, on this planet, there are both male and female carnivores, and somehow, we fall in love. I have been so afflicted more than once.

Vampires can be like anybody else, it should not surprise us if they view their victims as prey and food animals, and reserve their true regard for their peers: Other vampires. Nor should it surprise us if one vampire falls in love with another vampire; even if in your world vampires cannot have children.

Romance and love does not have to be about having children. Ask any homosexual married couple. Ask any woman that marries after menopause, or marries after hysterectomy or other disease or surgery that prevents her from having children.

Vampires are a certain kind of predator for food, as are most humans, and that is all you have to use from the clichés about them; discard anything you think about vampires that would prevent them from falling in love with each other. Like many authors before you, write about ***your*** vampires, not somebody else's.

Comment: Thank you for this, that really got me thinking! Thanks!

Comment: P.S. If they are trying to revert to human; similar to my daughter that keeps wanting to be a vegetarian but falls off the wagon after about three months, every time. They can "miss" their human days of caring for humans, even when their sympathies are no longer felt. Like missing a childhood game that is no longer fun, but you remember you had such great fun playing it, back then. It makes for a complex vampire.

Comment: Who says vampires can't have children? Maybe the vampiress is pregnant, and they're seeking a place where they might raise their sweet bloodsucking baby away from the torches and pitchforks. :P But yeh, @DerpymanMT, do what Amadeus says - write your own vampires. Forget everything that's been written before, and get creative.

Comment: @Galastel Brings a rather new gruesome meaning to "eating for two". I presume the fetus, nourished on its mother's vampire blood, would be a vampire before it was born. We know it is healthy when it starts to chew its way out! So perhaps a new meaning for "labor pains" as well.

Answer (score 4):

This will be closed in 3… 2…

But here's an idea. Make them suddenly **not** vampires. Hilarity ensues as they have to eat vegetables, get day-jobs, and actually learn how to have a conversation now that the whole sensuously-evil aura isn't working out.

The quest is about them trying to become vampires again, but along the way they are forced to question their vampire lifestyle: sleeping all day, indiscriminate exchange of body fluids, the pretentious fashions, sleeping in a box of dirt….

It is a metaphor for becoming an adult, and learning how to be person who gives back to society rather than always taking.

Comment: Well here is the thing they are trying not to become vampires anymore, but this does sound interesting.